# Is there a way to use the EventToCommand of the MVVMLight in the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf?

Tags: wpf, eventtocommand

I have used System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF library with MVVM Light.

I deleted System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF library because it's publishing date is old. And I installed Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf library and updated related to content.

The work went smoothly except for one.
The problem is if I use the interaction of Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf with EventToCommand of the MVVMLight as below, compiler shows error.

```
 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
 xmlns:mvvm="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CPUSelectedCommand}"
                         PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                         EventArgsConverter="{localConverters:SelectedItemConverter}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The error message is "error MC3074: There is not EventToCommand tag in the XML namespace 'http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight'."

If I use CallMethodAction or InvokeCommand Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf then works well but I have to use EventToCommand because of to pass the parameter to the Command.

What I should do to solve this problem?
Could someone tell me the solution?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The `EventToCommand` class in MvvmLight inherits from `System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction<T>` and cannot be added to the `Actions` property of a `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.EventTrigger`.

So your options are:

1. Revert back to using `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`.
2. Create your own `EventToCommand` type that inherits from `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.TriggerAction<T>`. You may start from the existing implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/1f67dfbcfb776b785727c1505566dc5f7c72a891/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform%20(NET45)/Command/EventToCommand.cs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: [See also](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/issues/96)